# Does this method close the MongoDB connection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, next.js

I have a method that connects to the MongoDB, but I can't figure out if this connection ends after a call was made or not.

This is the method:

```
import { Db, MongoClient } from "mongodb";

let cachedConnection: { client: MongoClient; db: Db } | null = null;

export async function connectToDatabase(mongoUri?: string, database?: string) {
  if (!mongoUri) {
    throw new Error(
      "Please define the MONGO_URI environment variable inside .env.local"
    );
  }

  if (!database) {
    throw new Error(
      "Please define the DATABASE environment variable inside .env.local"
    );
  }

  if (cachedConnection) return cachedConnection;

  cachedConnection = await MongoClient.connect(mongoUri, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  }).then((client) => ({
    client,
    db: client.db(database),
  }));

  return cachedConnection!;
}
```

I use this with Next.js and I am afraid that the app I am actually doing goes down if there will be too many connections. Intuitively, I think that the mongoDB connection ends after a call, but I am not sure.

Comment: The bigger issue here is a) your memoisation ignores `mongoUri` and `database` so if you call it twice with different arguments, you get the same connection b) The warnings about environment variables should not be part of this function, but be placed where the environment variables are read c) you're caching the connection itself, not the promise for it, which introduces a race condition (when calling the function multiple times before `MongoClient.connect()` fullfills, you call it multiple times)

Comment: uhmmm.. so do I have to remove the `if then return` statement to avoid getting the same connection?